# iCloudHelper spams system.log about accepting TOS

Tags: icloud, macos

I am seeing my system.log on my mac being flooded by iCloud Helper error messages dealing with the need to accept a TOS agreement. Problem is, the Apple ID that is listed in the message is not one of my current IDs but rather an 9 digit integer.

I have already logged into my two Apple ID accounts on iCloud and they are fine. Is there someplace I can look on disk for this? Everything seems to be working okay; I just want to eliminate the spam from a very overloaded Mavericks system.log.

Here is the log snippet with the integer replaced with XXXXX

> `Nov 4 00:14:56 himeko com.apple.iCloudHelper[5272]: AOSKit ERROR: Setup request failed, appleID=XXXXXXXXX, url=https://setup.icloud.com/setup/get_account_settings, requestHeaders= { "Accept-Language" = "en-us"; Authorization = "Basic ..."; "X-APNS-Token" = 5aa69ef2a363d57292517edb985201b3e6ca340c04385511709c4a8be22180ea; "X-Aos-Accept-Tos" = false; "X-Mme-Client-Info" = " "; "X-Mme-Country" = US; "X-Mme-Timezone" = PST; }, error=Error Domain=AOSErrorDomain Code=5003 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AOSErrorDomain error 5003.)" UserInfo=0x7f99e9d3dc30 {HttpStatusCode=409, DialogInfo={ AlternateButtonLabel = ""; AlternateButtonLink = ""; Body = "MOBILEME_TERMS_OF_SERVICE_UPDATE"; DefaultButtonLabel = "mme.setupservice.SetupServiceJS.OK"; DefaultButtonLink = ""; DialogType = TOSDialog; ErrorID = "MOBILEME_TERMS_OF_SERVICE_UPDATE"; Header = ""; HelpLink = ""; description = "This account needs to accept the ToS"; localizedError = "MOBILEME_TERMS_OF_SERVICE_UPDATE"; protocolVersion = 2; }}, httpStatusCode=409, responseHeaders= { "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, private"; "Content-Encoding" = gzip; "Content-Length" = 404; "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"; Date = "Mon, 04 Nov 2013 08:14:55 GMT"; : },`

Answer (score 1):

Open system preferences, click on each iCloud account and pause for a second or two and then accept the terms for that account.

Or, delete accounts that you don't need.

Either will remove the spamming.

Answer (score 0):

I had already tried that to no avail. Turns out I had to do two things: 
Use the iCloud address associated with my main apple id to log into the cloud app and add my old MobileMe account ( via its iCloud login) to the lists ( even though its marked as inactive and void of content).

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Glad you had it sorted. What is "log into the cloud app" and how does what you did differ from just deleting the account from iCloud preference pane and setting it up again?